# Getting Vars to bind properly across multiple files

Tags: clojure

I am just learning Clojure and am having trouble moving my code into different files.

I keep detting this error from the appnrunner.clj -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: -run-application in this context
```

It seems to be finding the namespaces fine, but then not seeing the Vars as being bound...  Any idea how to fix this?

Here's my code:

APPLICATION RUNNER -

```
(ns src/apprunner
  (:use src/functions))

(def input-files [(resource-path "a.txt") (resource-path "b.txt") (resource-path "c.txt")])
(def output-file (resource-path "output.txt"))

(defn run-application []
  (sort-files input-files output-file))

(run-application)
```

APPLICATION FUNCTIONS -

```
(ns src/functions
  (:use clojure.contrib.duck-streams))

(defn flatten [x]
  (let [s? #(instance? clojure.lang.Sequential %)]
    (filter
      (complement s?)
      (tree-seq s? seq x))))

(defn resource-path [file]
  (str "C:/Users/Alex and Paula/Documents/SoftwareProjects/MyClojureApp/resources/" file))

(defn split2 [str delim]
  (seq (.split str delim)))

(defstruct person :first-name :last-name)

(defn read-file-content [file]
  (apply str
    (interpose "\n" (read-lines file))))

(defn person-from-line [line]
  (let [sections (split2 line " ")]
    (struct person (first sections) (second sections))))

(defn formatted-for-display [person]
  (str (:first-name person) (.toUpperCase " ") (:last-name person)))

(defn sort-by-keys [struct-map keys]
  (sort-by #(vec (map % [keys])) struct-map))

(defn formatted-output [persons output-number]
  (let [heading (str "Output #" output-number "\n")
        sorted-persons-for-output (apply str (interpose "\n" (map formatted-for-display (sort-by-keys persons (:first-name :last-name)))))]
    (str heading sorted-persons-for-output)))

(defn read-persons-from [file]
  (let [lines (read-lines file)]
    (map person-from-line lines)))

(defn write-persons-to [file persons]
  (dotimes [i 3]
    (append-spit file (formatted-output persons (+ 1 i)))))

(defn sort-files [input-files output-file]
  (let [persons (flatten (map read-persons-from input-files))]
    (write-persons-to output-file persons)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not naming your namespaces correctly!

You should do something like this instead:

---

```
;;; in file src/apprunner/core.clj
;;; (namespace names should contain at least one dot for things
;;; not to go into the default package... or some such thing)
(ns apprunner.core
  (:use apprunner.functions)

;;; the rest of your code for this file follows unchanged
```

---

```
;;; in file src/apprunner/functions.clj
(ns apprunner.functions
  (:use clojure.contrib.duck-streams))

;;; the rest of your code for this file follows unchanged
```

---

Running the above at the REPL (`(use 'apprunner.core)` etc.) works fine for me.

To summarise what was the problem here: Namespace names should contain dots where paths to files definining them contain slashes / backslashes (not that I mean *relative* paths -- relative to some directory which is actually on the classpath). Also, the `src/` directory is the one you put in your classpath, so you don't include a `src.` part in your namespace names. See e.g. the `src/foo/bar/baz.clj` vs. `foo.bar.baz` example in my answer to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459405/how-can-i-use-one-file-from-my-project-in-another-file).

Oh, and by the way, figuring out the classpath *is* difficult, period. So, be sure not to let yourself be discouraged by issues of this sort! :-) You might want to include info on how you run your code if you've got more namespace or classpath-related questions or if the above doesn't solve the problem for you, though.