# How to call a Clojure function from another project on my PC

Tags: clojure

I have two separate Leiningen projects on my PC (the result of running `lein new alpha` and `lein new beta` on the same directory). In addition to the usual `core.clj` file, the `alpha` project contains also a file called `src/alpha/utils.clj` with a function called `plus`.

Calling `plus` from it sibling file `core.clj` is no problem:

```clj
;  src/alpha/core.clj

(ns alpha.core
  (:require [alpha.utils :as u]))

(u/plus 2 3)
;; 5
```

The question is: How do I call that `plus` function from the `beta` project; esp.from `src/beta/core.clj`?

I found [a similar-sounding question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459405/how-can-i-use-one-file-from-my-project-in-another-file) but that is about calling a function stored in a separate file in the same project (the cooperating namespaces (`foo.bar` and `foo.quux.baz`) have the same prefix).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @possum, the solution is to create a symbolic link in a top-level subdirectory called `checkouts` in the `beta` project ("the client").  Here are the commands for MS Windows:

```
mkdir \path\to\beta\checkouts
cd \path\to\beta\checkouts
mklink /D alpha \path\to\alpha
```

Now it is possible to start the REPL on `beta` and run  `(require '[alpha.utils :as u])`